# GetCommandLineArgs triggers "Index was outside the bounds of the array" anomaly on VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, command-line-arguments, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a program written in vb.net that when I run from the debugger runs fine but when I run the .exe file I get a "Index was outside the bounds of the array" anomaly. classic "it was running fine before" situation.

[image]

I placed a bunch of logs within my code to try to catch where is that anomaly being trigger, rebuilt and ran the .exe and I found that it fails when it runs this command:

```
myIntVariable= CInt(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()(1))
lblStationNum.Text = "Station " + myIntVariable.ToString()
```

My command line argument in the properties option is set to 1, but it seems that when I run the executable it is defaulting to 0.(my variable is used to assign the value to "estacion")

[image]

I've seen in different posts in the Microsoft developer community that this problem was fixed many updates ago so I am pretty confused, the station that displays this problem is running VS2019 v16.11.23. running .NET Framework 4.6.1

Any feedback is appreciated, let me know if you need more details, there are virtually none since this happened after returning from the weekend.

I tried hard coding the value, it causes a conflict since I need to run 6 separate instances of the app at the same time.

Comment: Well, use the debugger :)

Comment: _it was running fine before_: Never think or say this, it merely prevents you from proper troubleshooting and finding the culprit.

Comment: You say "when I run the .exe file..." how do you do so?

Comment: Keep in mind that even if your application hasn't been modified, MS constantly updates _.NET_ and _.NET Framework_.  They may have fixed a bug that allowed you to do things that you shouldn't have been able to or they may have introduced a bug in an update due to inadequate testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/debug-command-line-arguments-are-not-passed-to-exe/344217)

I created a shortcut to my .exe, on right-click->properties->Shortcut I added my argument on the target

eg
Target: "C:\MyAppsLocation\myFile.exe" **1**

Double clicking the shortcut sends the argument and my executable now runs.

Comment: While what you did works, you don't need a shortcut unless you actually want a shortcut. You can run your app form the commandline. You can open a console window and type the path of your executable followed by desired argument or use Windows' Run function by right-clicking the Start button. You can also run it from a batch file.

Comment: Yes, you are right; but I failed to point out that this program is released to a production floor station, and the request is to have a shortcut accessible for them on the Desktop, "with a pretty icon" was a phrase used actually. we don't want operators messing with command prompts.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net, array indexes start with `0`. This means `(1)` is the **second** argument, not the first. Since there is only the single `1` value in the arguments box, this is past the end of the arguments array, causing your error. You want this instead:

```
myIntVariable= CInt(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()(0))
```

---

Also, you should update to at least 4.6.2, as 4.6.1 *no longer receives security patches*. The 4.8 series would be even better, and would likely not even require any code changes.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The `GetCommandLineArgs` returns the executable file name as the first element of the array so your proposed solution would always return that, regardless of whether there were any additional arguments or not. The original code is correct in order to get the first actual argument. The problem is that the OP is not passing any actual argument(s) when not running in the debugger.